# Inserting a row in a table depending on the values of columns in a different table in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table called reportValues:

```
id isNew isExclusive isPremium
10  1       1          0 
11  0       0          1
12  1       0          1
```

and I have a table called productProperties

isNew has propertyId of 1, isExclusive has a propertyId of 2, and isPremium has a propertyId of 3.

```
id propertyId
10 1
10 2
11 3
12 1
12 3
```

I need to add rows into productProperties depending on the boolean values of table reportValues, how do you do this with a stored procedure? I am thinking you need some kind of if statement, but I couldn't find an example.

Comment: *add rows into productProperties depending on the boolean values of table reportValues*: please describe the logic you want. You gave no clue about how to interpret the flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this.  The boolean values are unpivoted using `CROSS APPLY` and assigned 1,2,3 propertyId's.  Then the converted values are inserted `WHERE` the boolean property is `TRUE`, i.e. v.property=1.  The following stored procedure inserts into the productProperties table and checks to make sure the values don't already exists.  Maybe that's not necessary?  It could be commented out or deleted.

```
drop proc if exists dbo.productPropertiesInsert;
go
create proc  dbo.productPropertiesInsert
as
set nocount on;

insert productProperties
select v.id, v.propertyId
from reportValues rv
     cross apply (values (1, rv.id, rv.isNew), 
                         (2, rv.id, rv.isExclusive), 
                         (3, rv.id, rv.isPremium)) 
                         v(propertyId, id, property)
where v.property=1
      /* optional code? */
      and not exists(select 1 
                     from productProperties p_in
                     where v.id=p_in.id
                           and v.propertyId=p.propertyId);
go
```